# Degree of a map and Suspension

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I want to verify the following "geometric" proof that if we have a continuous $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ then $\textit{deg}f=degSf$ , $Sf$ denoting the suspended map from $S^{n+1}$ to $S^{n+1}$.

It is safe to assume that $f$ is onto, since if it isn't, neither is $Sf$ so both maps have degree zero.

**Conjecture**: For every surjective $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ there exists $y$ such that $\#f^{-1}(y)=\textit{finite}$ .

If the conjecture is true then we can compute the degree of $f$ and $Sf$ from the preimages of above $y$ either considered in $S^n$ or in the "equatorial" $S^n \hookrightarrow S(S^n)=S^{n+1}$ and since $Sf|_{eq(S^n)}=f$ the local degrees are the same and therefore the total degrees.

**(Attempted) Proof of conjecture**: $f$ can be homotoped to $\tilde{f}$ that is both onto and smooth (*not sure about how to do both*). By Sard's theorem we can find a a regular value, since the critical values have measure $0$ and the image of our $\tilde{f}$ is the whole $S^n$. But this means that $\tilde{f}^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth compact manifold of $n-n=0$ dimension therefore is just finite points.

I would appreciate comments and/or corrections to the following proof. I am aware that $degf=degSf$ can easily be proved algebraicaly, I am just trying to produce a different proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture is false because space filling curves exist. Here is an "explicit example" Take a surjective map $f:S^1\rightarrow S^2$, suspend it to $Sf:S^2\rightarrow S^3$. Then postcomposing with the Hopf fibration $\nu:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ will give you a map with the desired properties: $\nu^{-1}(y)$ will be a circle for every point and as the map $Sf$ is surjective $Sf^{-1}\nu^{-1}(y)$ will have an infinite number of points for all $y$.

I think it is a good idea to homotope your map to a smooth one: You can homotope to a smooth curve and then suspend. The map might not be smooth at the north and southpole but everywhere else it will be smooth. By a small perturbation (leaving the equator untouched) you can make the map smooth. The degree can be calculated for a regular value on the equator which you can relate to the degree of the unsuspended map.

Comment: Thank you , your counterexample is very clear! Yet, It seems to me that your second paragraph contradicts the first. If we can find a regular value on the "equator" of $S^{n+1}$, why can't we do it on the original $S^n$?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being very clear: You can always homotope a map to a smooth one. For the homotoped map calculating the degree is easy: You take the preimage of a regular value and calculate the local degrees. The degree is a homotopy invariant so you also computed it for the original non-smooth map.

Comment: Now we start with a smooth map $f:S^{n}\rightarrow S^{n}$ (this has finite number of preimages) and take its suspension $Sf:S^{n+1}\rightarrow S^{n+1}$. This is not smooth at the north and southpole, but it can be made smooth without changing the map around the equator (both in the domain and codomain). Then you can relate the preimages of $y\in S^n\subset S^{n+1}$  nder $Sf$ to the preimage of $f$ of the same value $y$.

Comment: This computes the degree of the suspension of a smooth map. But since the degree is homotopy invariant, and every continuous map is homotopic to a smooth map, you also computed it for any map.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome